# custom keyboard - selecting a key from popup keyboard by keyup

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

i want select key from keyboard popup not by click on it but when keyup on it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmsU5.jpg)

am tryed this code when iam not choosed anything on popup will disappear after keyup and working but i cannot when i keyup on key from popup not working.

```
 keyboardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             keyboardView.closing();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And this my code for onCreateInputView

```
keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.letters_small);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
```

Comment: no any answer to now :\

Comment: i need answer please

Comment: didi you find any solution?